# Swift 3 - How do I Submit an HTTP Form from URL Data Request

Tags: javascript, html, ios, swift3, httpwebrequest

I am a bit confused an what to do at this point. So far I have made the connection to the website that I want to submit a login form to. When I go to the site, it requires a username and password which then lets you sign in an goes to the logged in version of the site. The source code of the site contains place holders for the input of text. The string of the place holders are stored as variables. I assumed that I would need to search for it within the returned http data. The data from the login page comes back successfully and the printed output contains these placeholders. I get the username and password from the user through text fields but how would I go about telling the website to "insert" these user values as the site fields and to submit the form (basically press "Sign in") in order to get to the logged in version of the website? When I view the source of the website I am working with, the code is in JavaScript. Would this require jQuery or JSON parsing (GET/POST Requests) or am I trying the wrong things?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    final var USERNAME_FIELD = "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$Username"
    final var PASSWORD_FIELD = "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$Password"

    @IBOutlet weak var gobuttom: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var passField: UITextField!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        gobuttom.isEnabled = true

        data_request("https://example.com")


    }


    func data_request(_ url:String)
    {
        let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: url)!
        let session = URLSession.shared

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        let paramString = "data=test"
        request.httpBody = paramString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
            (
            data, response, error) in

            guard let _:NSData = data as NSData?, let _:URLResponse = response, error == nil else {
                print("error")
                return
            }

            if let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
            {
                print(dataString)
            }
        }

        task.resume()

    }



    @IBOutlet weak var usernameField: UITextField!

    @IBAction func usernameChanged(_ sender: Any) {
        print("textfield : \(String(describing: usernameField.text))")

        gobuttom.isEnabled = true
    }



    @IBAction func goPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        if(usernameField.text != "" && passField.text != ""){
            print("OK")
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This is basically correct (though you might set the `Content-Type` header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`). The thing is, when you're trying to scrape a site and replicate the login process, there are often hidden fields in the login page that include dynamically created session identifier tags and the like. So you often can't bypass the login page, but rather have to request that first, capture the hidden fields, and then include them in your actual login request shown above.

Comment: FYI, nowadays we'd avoid using `NSMutableURLRequest` but rather do `var request = URLRequest(...)`. Likewise you would use `Data` and `String` rather than `NSData` and `NSString`. It works the way you've got it, but we generally stay with Swift types where we can. It just leads to Swiftier, more easily read code and avoids a lot of unnecessary casts.

Comment: @Rob So what would be the next step in order to find those hidden fields? Obviously if i go to the source code I can find the keyword "hidden" for those occurrences but would I need a specific asset such as jQuery or Alamofire to continue?

Comment: Yep, you request the login page, parse the HTML looking for those hidden fields, capture those values and use them in the second request that actually logs in. (You don't always have to do it, but in my experience you generally do.) There can also be cookies, even if you don't see any hidden fields there, so you might have to do the login page request before you attempt the login. Sometimes it's useful to watch the web-based login process via something like [Charles](http://charlesproxy.com) or [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org) or with your browser's "developer" tools.

Comment: When doing this programmatically, jQuery is not applicable (though you should see if any AJAX calls are going back and forth or anything complicated going on in the JavaScript that you might need to replicate; this is less likely). When submitting the request, Alamofire is really nice tool to get you out of the weeds of composing the second "login with this userid/password" request. Making `x-www-form-urlencoded` requests can be complicated (e.g. percent encoding of values in the `httpBody`) and Alamofire simplifies this a bit for you. Scraping is still very complicated, but Alamofire helps.

Comment: Finally, before you invest a lot of time in this (and it will take a fair amount of time, IMHO), you might want to check the terms of service for the site you're going against, because often the programmatic scraping of the site is explicitly forbidden.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for your response. The app I am working on currently exists for android for a couple of years now and the source code exists online by an individual. I would assume that that would mean the scrapping would be allowed.

Comment: Not to belabor the point, just because someone else did it doesn't mean it doesn't violate the ToS. Check the web site for terms. By the way, if you have an android app that already successfully scrapes the site you're interested in, it may be easier to use that as your template rather than the time consuming reverse-engineering from the web site's HTML. Someone may have done this time consuming research for you. No guarantees, but it might be easier to approach the problem from that angle.

Answer (score 0):

Http scrapping in Swift is fairly complex. There isn' really much information on how to do it unless you work with web development regularly. Here is a great tutorial on swift scraping: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gscuaUSkxnI